# internal server error during accessing magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I have changed some setting in the URL rewrites in the Magento admin panel. Now, the URL is showing correctly on front end, but I am having a problem accessing the admin panel. It shows "internal server error with 500 error". Please help me with this problem.

Comment: 6th Magento question? Have you considered asking your Magento questions in the Magento forums? I would think that's the best place to get help with it.

Comment: Actually the Magento forums aren't that helpful either.  I'd suggest following the proposal for a Magento-specific StackExchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9869/magento

Comment: Show us the stack trace, and show us the core_config_data entries which path contains 'url'.

Comment: i have a similar problem : i actually run a magento on a server, everything is running well exepted where i try to save the magento configuration from admin panel... the server returns me a error 500 everytime , but if i go back on previous page , everything is working fine , i m wondering if it s juste a php or mysql misconfiguration but i don t know what variable to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace your .htaccess file with a known good copy.  Error 500's can be caused by the wrong permissions as well.  I doubt this is the case with you since there is no actual admin folder it is done with the url rewrites.  None the less here is a post I made for people who are getting error 500:
[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/220253/)

Also here is my URL rewrites from my magento site incase you do not have a backup copy:

```
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
```

Answer (score 0):

The best route to take is to go into your magento directory and (ALWAYS BACKUP FIRST!) remove all your .htaccess edits. If there is a .htaccess file for your admin directory specifically, that would be the best place to start (temporarily?) removing these edits. Then slowly put them back into place to find out your problem and fix it.

Good luck!
Dennis M.